# What is the cause of D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView while implementing a contextmenu on cardview?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-recyclerview, contextmenu, android-cardview

On long press on the card, i get a menu that I am setting in onCreateContextMenu(), but the executing doesnt go inside onMenuItemClick() where I intend to do some actions according to the option selected by user.

On touching the item in the context menu, i get the below error.

**08-15 13:47:31.144 19269-19446/com.sagnikdas.nav D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x9d250d80 (MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView) with handle 0x8c51cfd0**

Below is the code:
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.sagnikdas.nav.CustomAdapter.MESSAGE";
private Context context;
private ArrayList<MyData> my_data;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyData> my_data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.my_data = my_data;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardlayout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.title.setText(my_data.get(position).getTitle());

    if (my_data.get(position).getImageURL() != null || !my_data.get(position).getImageURL().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        Glide.with(context).load(my_data.get(position).getImageURL()).into(holder.imageView);
    } else {
        Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.imageback).into(holder.imageView);//load(my_data.get(position).getImageURL()).into(holder.imageView);
        //holder.imageView.setImageDrawable();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return my_data.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, View.OnClickListener,
        MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener{

    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView title;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title1);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getTitle() == "Save"){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Item saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(item.getTitle()=="Share"){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Item Shared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DisplayNewsActivity.class);
        String messageUrl = my_data.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUrl();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, messageUrl);
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select an Action");
        menu.add("Save");
        menu.add("Share");
    }

}
```

Card Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_margin="4dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
card_view:cardElevation="7dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
card_view:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Title section"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="13sp"/>


</LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: That's a `DEBUG` message, not `ERROR`.

Comment: Why is it not working if there is no issue with the code. I cant see the toast message. Reaper

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect menu items with a corresponding menu item click listener, like so:

```
@Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Select an Action");
            menu.add("Save").setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            menu.add("Share").setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        }
```

or add `onContextItemSelected()` method in your activity and put the code from `onMenuItemClick()` there.

What about OpenGL message, it's probably related to Glide image loading. Try to listen to image errors.